# How to create face-detection masks (like in Snapchat/MSQRD/YouCam Fun)

Tags: filters, face-detection

How do you create these masks for live filter photo apps like this one?: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmRJk0ZJsZk

What image editing program would you need? What kind of format are these?

Comment: Are you asking about making your own application to do this or extending an existing one?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has more to do with video than photography.

Anyway, if you want to add face masks on an existing video, you just need a video application with tracking capabilities (e.g. After effects, Hitfilm express, DaVinci Resolve etc.)

If you want to do it real time on a video stream you need some kind of video processing library and face detection library (e.g. [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/))